# How to install and use a minecraft mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do I install and use a minecraft mod on ubuntu 18.04.1?

On the internet I have found many descriptions on how to do it (e.g. [here](https://www.minecraftmods.com/how-to-install-mods-for-minecraft-forge/) and [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-Mods-for-Minecraft-Forge/)) but either these instructions are out of date or do not work.

The mod to install is `Lucky Blocks` which seem to work only for version 1.12. Therefore I already installed a minecraft forge server version 1.12.

But now what? The instruction says to place the mod file (its a zip) into the mod folder. But neither in the client (in `~/.minecraft`) nor in the folder where I downloaded the forge version (`~/.minecraftForge12`) does such a folder exist. So create one? Where? Client or server? And then what to do exactly to use this mod?

I also want other users to be able to join this mod minecraft server from the outside. Do they have to install something? What? Where?

Here are the steps I did:

1. Installed forge server 12.2 on computer1
2. Created `mods` folder inside the forge server 12.2 on computer1
3. Copied the mod zip file into the `mods` folder inside the forge server 12.2 on computer1
4. Launching normal minecraft client. There is no `mods` to select from.

Comment: Just create the folder.

Comment: and put the mod file in. And then? What is the next step? And WHERE to create the folder? The normal minecraft installation or the forge server installation? Do I install it also on the outside computer?

Comment: You said you already had Forge running, so that's it. Just put the file in there and start Minecraft with Forge. Of course if it's a client-side mod as well, you need Forge on your client as well.

Comment: So you need a forge server with the mod on the `mods` folder, and for each player you need to have a forge client installed, without the mod on the `mods` folder. Is that now correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want to play on a server. In Singleplayer the client is enough.

Answer (score 0):

so your on a ubuntu, thats very similar to my ubuntu linux. alright so what you do is you click on resource packs, do the back arrow click on the mods folder and insert your .jar mod. to install you go to your mod, click download and download it. have fun messing around on amazing mods! to run you should install forge https://www.minecraft-downloads.com/minecraft-forge-mod-for-windows-and-mac/ you may need to install a program known as Wine Program Installer this program allows you to use windows and mac programs. and some mods dont work with each other. but to run you need a jar not a zip. hope you understand now!